# Can a pseudorandom generator ever be true random?

Tags: random, numbers, generator, random-seed

I can understand how using a seed for a pseudorandom gen such as the time does not make it truly random; but when a pseudorandom generator gets its seed from a hardware random number generator, doesn't the pseudorandom generator then become True Random, as its seed is gathered from a TRNG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, realize that individual numbers are not random or non-random: only large sets of numbers.

If you seed a PRNG from a truly random source, and then just keep calling the PRNG to get more numbers, then you will just have a pseudorandom *sequence* of numbers, albeit well seeded.

If you seed a PRNG with a truly random source and then fetch only one value from the PRNG, then you have a hash of a truly random number. If the PRNG's seed hashing function is good, this will be just as random as its input. If it's not, it might be more predictable (for example, a PRNG with only 64 bits of internal state will only produce 2^64 different values, regardless of how many bits you seed it with).

That's not to say that it's a bad idea--game simulations and Monte Carlo systems *should* use a fast PRNG seeded from a TRNG source to get the best compromise of speed and quality. But cryptographic applications need cryptographically secure random values, and that's trickier.

Answer (score 0):

No

Good seeds are necessity, but they won't change the nature (and flaws) of the PRNG.

For example, even with good absolutely true random seed RNG such as LCG will still experience correlated sampling at high dimensions